# Why is rotate adding space before and after my element in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I'm creating my own custom product badges and noticed when I rotate -45deg and use before and after there is a space added in Firefox

I originally had the same problem in Chrome but adding `transform: translateZ(0);` was able to fix it. I tried negative margin and it made the before and after not look as wide as the div at the top.

```css
.product-badge {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1978AB;
    width: 92px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateZ(0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
.product-badge:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    right: 100%;
    border-width: 0 0 40px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #1978AB transparent;
}
.product-badge:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-width: 40px 0 0 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #1978AB;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-badge"></div>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mts9zgpv/1/)